# Get the highest revision number from a subversion dump file in Perl or shell

Tags: perl, svn, bash, svn-administraton

I would like to extract the highest revision number in a subversion dump file.
Besides parsing the file line by line, is there any easier (and hopefully faster) way using standard perl (no extra modules allowed on the server) or bash shell scripting?

Comment: bah, I found it myself, so for everyone who has the same problem:
`cat Dump1.dump | grep "Revision-number" | tail -n 1 | sed 's/Revision-number\:\ //g'`

Comment: so write it as the solution and cash in! :)

Comment: maybe you should answer yourself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you created a dump file using

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo > Dump1.dump
```

The you can find the last revision number with this one-liner:

```
grep --binary-files=text "Revision-number" Dump1.dump | tail -n 1 | sed 's/Revision-number\:\ //g'
```

Alternately to avoid grepping the entire file, use tac (cat backwards) and stop on the first (last) match. Eliminates the need for tail on the large output of grep, and saves processing time.

```
tac Dump1.dump | grep -m1 --binary-files=text "Revision-number" | sed 's/Revision-number\:\ //g'
```

Comment: Many dump files will be considered binary by grep and will not attempt to match.
grep "Revision-number" /svnrepos/reponame/20130408.dump
Binary file /svnrepos/reponame/20130408.dump matches  So I will edit your answer to force textual matching anyway

Answer (score 3):

I can subvert this solution, no pun intended, by simply checking in a text file that contains something like

```
Revision-number: 720
```

The output of the grep looks like this:

```
-bash-3.2$ grep "Revision-number:" test.dump.2
Revision-number: 0
Revision-number: 1
Revision-number: 2
Revision-number: 720
```

To really do this properly the dump file needs to be parsed.  I wrote a perl script using the SVN::Dumpfile module and just looped through the revisions until I got to the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use SVN::Dumpfile;
use strict;

my $df = new SVN::Dumpfile;
$df->open('/usr/tmp/test.dump.2');

my $revision=-1;
while (my $node = $df->read_node()) {
  if ($node->is_rev) {
    $revision = $node->header('Revision-number');
  }
}

print "$revision\n";
```